# What would happen to the drain current of a D-MOSFET at cutoff voltage when we are going to plot the tranconductance curve?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, fet, transconductance

Here,

$$I_{DSS} = 8 \,\textrm{mA}$$
$$V_P = -6 \,\textrm{V} $$

Equation for the drain current,

$$ I_D = I_{DSS} \left(1 - \frac{V_{GS}}{V_P}\right)^2 $$

So, the cut-off voltage is where the Drain current (Id) is zero. But at pinch-off voltage, drain current is zero as well according to the first graph. Then what would happen at the cut-off voltage if I want to extrapolate this curve? Considering cut off voltage is the opposite polarity of the pinch-off voltage but shares the same value.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Extrapolate in what way? Note that real MOSFETs have an exponential cutoff region (subthreshold conduction); the quadratic only applies in the above-threshold region.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. In the second image, it feels like there is drain current at +6 V which is 32 mA. I am having a really hard time to understand the graph and plotting.

Comment: If that function is the definition of current vs. gate voltage, then yes, it would be 32mA at 6V. What is your question..?

Comment: @TimWilliams My question is, How come there is drain current at the cut-off voltage? Does it not have to zero according to the definition of the cut-off voltage? Current at 6 V does not make any sense to me.

Comment: The cutoff is -6, not 6... "Cutoff" and "pinchoff" are synonymous.

Comment: @TimWilliams Then why do some sources say cutoof and pinchoff are same in value but opposite in polarity?

Comment: Please edit your post to show citations of both.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have edited my post and added the confusing part. One thing, why did someone replace Idss with K?

Comment: @Ghost, I looked over your original post and the \$I_{DSS}\$ was missing. So a \$\kappa\$ was added. I changed that to  \$I_{DSS}\$. You can see the edit history by clicking on the "edited <time> ago" link below the post.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Lowercase kappa is the traditional representation. As the original lacked a coefficient, I added the generic one. | Ghost: please provide sources (links, citations) for these materials.  Your 2nd-last image seems to be an erroneous one: notice how the voltmeter is connected, it's reading Vsg not Vgs. It's also reading a JFET, not a MOSFET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drain current isn't **zero** at the cut-off (aka pinch-off) voltage. It has a defined low value at given \$V_\text{DS}\$. And with even more negative \$V_\text{GS}\$, the drain current decreases further *exponentially*.

The current value is somewhat arbitrary, so a more concrete definition is that, at the cut-off voltage, the current dependence on gate voltage changes from being exponential to square.

Bwlow is an image from *"The Art of Electronics"* (Section 3.3), which is a very good read about your question. As you can see, the "cut-off voltage" is a rather arbitrary point on the \$I_\text D(V_\text{GS})\$-curve, here taken at 10 nA of drain current. But as I stated above, a more concrete way.

[image]

Comment: Then why does the equation say zero?

Comment: Extrapolating that equation all the way to the cut-off voltage overstays its welcome  It simply doesn't apply anymore at and below the pinch-off voltage.